# ngFor only displays the last item in array

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I have an array of Persons in my component and when I try to display names property using *ngFor, it only displays the last person in the array.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
   <ul *ngFor="let person of Persons" class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
      <li><a href="#">{{person.personName}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please note that it only happens when I try to display it within the sidebar of a Bootstrap theme I'm using. However, in the developer tool I can see that the other names have been loaded but they are not being displayed to the screen for some reason.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/ye5lUMw0i5cHc87NIiFe

Comment: There are no issues seems to be in the code. Can you post a plunker?

Comment: Can you replicate it on a plunker..

Comment: Remove all css and then check, some css might be affecting your view

Comment: I've never used Plunker before, but this is the best I could do in terms of replication: https://plnkr.co/ye5lUMw0i5cHc87NIiFe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
        <li *ngFor="let person of Persons" ><a href="#">{{person.personName}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much! Wonder why using it in `li` worked but didn't work in `ul`...?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty You have put *ngFor on <ul> so when rendering it was creating one <ul> tag for each person. maybe in your container css only one <ul> tag is allowed to be shown.